# How can I add ImageView's with swipe option

Tags: android, uiimageview

[IMAGE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs4br.png) How can I achive effect shown in image. Im working on browser and for choosing current active tab I want to build something similarlike this. User will be able to swipe view right or left and if user click on view there will be zooming animation to fit the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library to swipe between images with effects:
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

```
dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

Add the Slider to your layout:

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
/>
```

Wiki:
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Slider-view

Comment: Thank you Zahid, its really helped me. Thanks